# When DOMNodeInserted event is fire upadateCount function works as expected but not when DOMNodeRemoved is fire which again target the same function?

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML**

here is the left and right button in HTML to remove list items and add list items respectively.

```
<div id="groceries">
           <h1>Buy Groceries<span id="counter">0</span></h1>
           <ul id="list"></ul>

           <div class="left button"><a  id ="lLink" href="">REMOVELISTITEM</a></div>     
           <div class="right button"><a  id ="rLink" href="">ADDLISTITEM</a></div>
         
           <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
```

**java script**

as click event fire on thise `<div class="button left"><a  id ="lLink" href="">REMOVELISTITEM</a></div>` and thise `<div class="button right"><a  id ="rLink" href="">ADDLISTITEM</a></div>` buttons list item removed or add into the list because of which Mutation events fire

```
Elist.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted',updateCount,false);
Elist.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved',updateCount,false);
```

which targets the same "updateCount" function but when the "DOMNodeInserted" event fire it calculate the right number of list items but not when "DOMNoderemoved" event fire why?

```
  function addListItem(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  newListnode = document.createElement('li');
  textNode = document.createTextNode("new list item");
  newListnode.appendChild(textNode);
  Elist.appendChild(newListnode);
}

function removeListItem(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Elist.removeChild(Elist.lastElementChild);
}

function updateCount(e){
  
    var numOfItems = Elist.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
    Ecounter.innerHTML = numOfItems;
}

ElLink.addEventListener('click',removeListItem,false);
ErLink.addEventListener('click',addListItem,false);

Elist.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted',updateCount,false);
Elist.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved',updateCount,false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding or Removing Items to/from DOM can take a little bit of time and therefore you do not have the results immediately. With this in mind, you should wait for the DOM to update, then do your job. putting a simple `setTimeout()` would put your code in a lower order in `eventCycle` and can solve your issue.

By the way, this is not the best approach tho, you can get the idea of what's happening and use a more advanced or optimized way to solve it

```js
var Elist = document.getElementById('list');
var ElLink = document.getElementById('lLink');
var ErLink = document.getElementById('rLink');
var Ecounter = document.getElementById('counter');

function addListItem(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  newListnode = document.createElement('li');
  textNode = document.createTextNode("new list item");
  newListnode.appendChild(textNode);
  Elist.appendChild(newListnode);
}

function removeListItem(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  Elist.removeChild(Elist.lastElementChild);
}

function updateCount(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var numOfItems = Elist.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
    Ecounter.innerHTML = numOfItems;
  }, 0);
}

ElLink.addEventListener('click', removeListItem, false);
ErLink.addEventListener('click', addListItem, false);

Elist.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', updateCount, false);
Elist.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', updateCount, true);
```

```html
<div id="groceries">
  <h1>Buy Groceries<span id="counter">0</span></h1>
  <ul id="list"></ul>

  <div class="left button"><a id="lLink" href="">REMOVELISTITEM</a></div>
  <div class="right button"><a id="rLink" href="">ADDLISTITEM</a></div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```